# How does ethereum's core functionalities work?

Tags: ether

Does ethereum's blokchain use a smart contract for it's core functionalities of transferring ether? If not then how does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ethereum doesn't use a smart contract to transfer ether between accounts.

As part of the Ethereum's World State each address has associated a balance. When a transfer is made the amount is substracted from the sender balance and the recipient balance is incremented.

Comment: Do you mean to say that world state is like a large key-value pair thing which has each address and the corresponding balance?

Comment: Yes, key is the address but value is a tuple: balance, nonce, code and storage. Code and storage are valid only for smart contracts.